# Mysql select rows where sum is equal to

Tags: mysql

I have a table A  like this :

```
ID | AMOUNT
1  | 10
2  | 30
3  | 40
```

I will want to find the lines with the sum of the amount equal to a value.

For example if I put the total amount to 70, my query must return id 2 and 3

Comment: _my query must return id..._ Where is your query? What is wrong with it?

Comment: This required a brute force approach and hence should be done at programming level in my opinion.

Comment: Also, what if there is already a row where `amount` is `70`? What output you want in this case?

Comment: I would like to return only a couple of lines that match. If there is already a row where amount is 70, my qery must return this row or rows 2 and 3

Comment: Imagine you have 3 rows of 35. Should you return 1 row or 2?

Answer (score 1):

Below query will return list of two rows whose sum is equal to your passed value. If there are more than one combinations of rows matching total sum it will return multiple lists. Check this on [Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9Tk6zXtNfCw8VP4Hr1pwUH/3). You just need to pass required total sum instead of *70*

```
SELECT If((t1.amount+t2.amount)=6,CONCAT(LEAST(t1.id,t2.id),',',GREATEST(t1.id,t2.id)),"") AS sumIds 
FROM testSum t1, testSum t2
WHERE (t1.amount+t2.amount)=6
AND t1.id!=t2.id
GROUP BY sumIds
```

Answer (score 0):

You know for every row what the value of the linked row should be (70-amount) so given this you can generate min and max amounts for every row, generate a blockid based on the minamount and a rownumber within the block. For example given

```
+------+--------+
| id   | amount |
+------+--------+
|    1 |     10 |
|    2 |     30 |
|    3 |     40 |
|    4 |     70 |
|    5 |     35 |
|    6 |     35 |
|    7 |     35 |
|    8 |     35 |
|    9 |     40 |
|   10 |     60 |
|   11 |     60 |
+------+--------+
11 rows in set (0.00 sec)

select id oldid,amount,
        70 - amount matching_amount,
        case when amount = 70 then 0
            when amount < 70 - amount then amount
            when amount >= 70 - amount then 70 - amount
        end as minamount,
        case when amount = 70 then amount
            when amount < 70 - amount then 70 - amount
            when amount >= 70 - amount then amount
        end as maxamount
from t
) s
cross join (select @bn:=0,@rn:=0,@pid:=0,@pmin:=999999) b
order by minamount,oldid;
```

You get

```
+-------+-----------+-----------+---------+-----------+------+
| oldid | minamount | maxamount | blockid | rownumber | pmin |
+-------+-----------+-----------+---------+-----------+------+
|     4 |         0 |        70 | 1       |         1 |    0 |
|     1 |        10 |        60 | 2       |         1 |   10 |
|    10 |        10 |        60 | 2       |         2 |   10 |
|    11 |        10 |        60 | 2       |         3 |   10 |
|     2 |        30 |        40 | 3       |         1 |   30 |
|     3 |        30 |        40 | 3       |         2 |   30 |
|     9 |        30 |        40 | 3       |         3 |   30 |
|     5 |        35 |        35 | 4       |         1 |   35 |
|     6 |        35 |        35 | 4       |         2 |   35 |
|     7 |        35 |        35 | 4       |         3 |   35 |
|     8 |        35 |        35 | 4       |         4 |   35 |
+-------+-----------+-----------+---------+-----------+------+
11 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

If you then do the same again and left join odd to even rows within blockid

```
select x.oldid,x.minamount,x.maxamount,x.blockid,x.rownumber, y.oldid,
        y.minamount,y.maxamount,y.blockid,y.rownumber
from
(
select oldid,minamount,maxamount,
        if(minamount <> @pmin,@bn:=@bn+1,@bn:=@bn) blockid,
        if(minamount <> @pmin,@rn:=1,@rn:=@rn+1) rownumber,
        @pmin:=minamount pmin
from
(
select id oldid,amount,
        70 - amount matching_amount,
        case when amount = 70 then 0
            when amount < 70 - amount then amount
            when amount >= 70 - amount then 70 - amount
        end as minamount,
        case when amount = 70 then amount
            when amount < 70 - amount then 70 - amount
            when amount >= 70 - amount then amount
        end as maxamount
from t
) s
cross join (select @bn:=0,@rn:=0,@pid:=0,@pmin:=999999) b
order by minamount,oldid
) x
left join
(
select oldid,minamount,maxamount,
        if(minamount <> @pmin1,@bn1:=@bn1+1,@bn1:=@bn1) blockid,
        if(minamount <> @pmin1,@rn1:=1,@rn1:=@rn1+1) rownumber,
        @pmin1:=minamount pmin
from
(
select id oldid,amount,
        70 - amount matching_amount,
        case when amount = 70 then 0
            when amount < 70 - amount then amount
            when amount >= 70 - amount then 70 - amount
        end as minamount,
        case when amount = 70 then amount
            when amount < 70 - amount then 70 - amount
            when amount >= 70 - amount then amount
        end as maxamount
from t
) a
cross join (select @bn1:=0,@rn1:=0,@pid1:=0,@pmin1:=999999) b
order by minamount,oldid
) y
on y.blockid = x.blockid and y.rownumber = x.rownumber + 1
where (x.rownumber % 2 > 0 and y.oldid is not null) or
        (x.rownumber % 2 > 0 and x.minamount = 0)
order by x.oldid;
```

You get

```
+-------+-----------+-----------+---------+-----------+-------+-----------+-----------+---------+-----------+
| oldid | minamount | maxamount | blockid | rownumber | oldid | minamount | maxamount | blockid | rownumber |
+-------+-----------+-----------+---------+-----------+-------+-----------+-----------+---------+-----------+
|     1 |        10 |        60 | 2       |         1 |    10 |        10 |        60 | 2       |         2 |
|     2 |        30 |        40 | 3       |         1 |     3 |        30 |        40 | 3       |         2 |
|     4 |         0 |        70 | 1       |         1 |  NULL |      NULL |      NULL | NULL    |      NULL |
|     5 |        35 |        35 | 4       |         1 |     6 |        35 |        35 | 4       |         2 |
|     7 |        35 |        35 | 4       |         3 |     8 |        35 |        35 | 4       |         4 |
+-------+-----------+-----------+---------+-----------+-------+-----------+-----------+---------+-----------+
5 rows in set (0.10 sec)
```

In Version 8 or above row number simulation can be simplified with row_number function